# Updating an outdated wiki page

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS wiki page on [how to navigate the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheWiki) is really outdated, especially the pictures. I found out the page was written when [www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org) used to redirect to [www.ros.org/wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki). I have made some changes to the page, but being relatively new to ROS, I want the opinion of experienced users so that I don't do more harm than good.

Also, is this the right place to ask this question?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310800/updating-an-outdated-wiki-page/) by [holadepo](https://answers.ros.org/users/38807/holadepo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wouldn't worry about it too much. Whoever "owns" that page is getting email notifications about your edits, so they'll probably correct anything awful. They probably appreciate your effort and your perspective as a newcomer is really valuable for a tutorial like that.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2018-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1